# do we need to truncate a large table before dropping?

Tags: oracle

it is said that we should always truncate a large table before dropping, it improves performance. Is it true?

Comment: "improves performance" - in what way? Do you mean performance of entire database, or do you mean that deletion of that table will go faster?

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/why-use-both-truncate-and-drop

Answer (score 12):

IMO in general if you simply want to drop a table then `DROP` is appropriate. It will release space the same way as `TRUNCATE` would and it will have the advantage of being atomic (no query will have the opportunity to see the table "empty").

From 10g+, a dropped table won't be deleted immediately however: if there is sufficient space it will be put in the [recycle bin](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#sthref2383). If you truncate a table first, no data will remain in the recycle bin. This may be why you have been told to truncate first (?).

In any case, if you want to bypass the recycle bin you could issue `DROP TABLE your_table PURGE` and this statement will be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends if you want to be able to roll back if something goes wrong.

Deletion of data records the deletion against the transaction logs of the database until you commit the change.

Truncation removes all the data from the table without recording those logs, so there can be a significant performance improvement in doing this. Just be sure you know what you are doing, as there's no way back.

Comment: `drop table` doesn't record logs either, does it? The OP said nothing about `delete`.

Comment: Good point. I made the assumption he was talking about the performance of the truncate itself. You may now proceed to mock me and hurl rocks at my house. :)

Comment: drop table can record logs--for instance "flashback" can restore a dropped table, if configured/enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea in order to reset the high water mark.

Comment: well, not really - once the table is dropped there *is* no HWM.